# Bootstrap grid specific layout

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

how do I make the bootstrap grid like this?
if ≥ 576px:
[image]

if < 576px:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It will do that for you **automatically**, but you can always add a custom media query as well if you want.

Comment: have you tried to so far? this is not a free coding for me site

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's col-xs-$ has the lowest max-width of 768px. I think you will have to add another class to your columns and then specify your CSS rule to that class

For example :

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 smaller-div-class">
   Col 1
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4 smaller-div-class">
   Col 2
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4 smaller-div-class">
   Col 3
 </div>
```

and so on... and add the style in smaller-div-class

```
 @media screen and (max-size<576px){
  .smaller-div-class{
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap rows each contain 12 columns, and each column should be confined to a row.

Considering you want three columns, you should specify that each has a width of `4` columns, as `12 / 3 = 4`. This is done by using `col-sm-4` as a class name.

The `col-sm-` prefix for columns is based on the 'Small' screen sizes, and actually **defaults** to the exact width you want of `576px`:

[image: Cheatsheet]

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background: green;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 one"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 two"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 three"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
            <h2>col1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
            <h2>col2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
            <h2>col3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
            <h2>col4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
            <h2>col5</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
            <h2>col6</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```